# Classico Pesto left outside for a week, used in recipe, still safe?

Tags: food-safety

---

So I thought I didn’t open my jar of pesto(on the counter) and used it in a recipe, but I just realized I used it before for the first time around a week ago. So it’s been sitting on the countertop, unrefrigerated, opened, for a week. Is botulism a concern due to the garlic in oil? What about other bacteria such as Staphylococcus?

Answer (score 2):

Whether this is homemade, or [this store bought version](https://www.classico.com/product/00041129000052/classico-signature-recipes-traditional-basil-pesto-sauce--spread-81-oz-jar), it needs to be refrigerated (if store bought, refrigerated after opening).  So, I would assume that this is not safe to consume at this point.  Having a lid does not protect you.

Comment: Would heating it to 100C help?

Comment: No...One week at the perfect temperature for pathogen growth is problematic to begin with.  Then there are heat resistant pathogens to worry about.  Get rid of it.